# Genymotion virtual device not play

Tags: android, genymotion

When i play device this show popup like below "Playe.exe has stopped working"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ram is not supporting
try to make use of less memory on ram(close other programs)

Comment: I have 4 gb ram and eclipse,virtual machine ,and genymotion are currently run .I also check with taskManager performance.

Comment: Do you try to run Genymotion inside another virtual machine ? If so, it is rather complex to achieve. Most virtualizing solutions can't embed a virtual machine themselves, or with a complex setup.

Comment: I have oracle virtual machine